# Sitecore Serialization using Sitecore CLI Installation Error

Tags: sitecore-cli

I am attempting to install Sitecore CLI 4.2.1 on Sitecore 10.0. The installation is fresh install of Sitecore 10.0. I keep getting this error below. This error will shut down Sitecore where I have to restore the files from a backup of files. All help is appreciated to resolve:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +96
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +62
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.<>c.<GetServicesConfigurators>b__2_0(XmlNode x) +114
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +241
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +193
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) +171
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection() +142
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider() +225
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider() +513
   Sitecore.DependencyInjection.SitecorePerRequestScopeModule..ctor() +13

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +234
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1153
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0
```

Comment: What version of the DLL exists in the bin directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Sitecore 10.0, the only version of the CLI that you can use is 2.0.0 (https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_CLI/2x/Sitecore_CLI_200.aspx)

[image: Sitecore CLI Compatibility Table]

Source: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000576

All versions above require Sitecore 10.1+