# Error when trying to sync items using Sitecore for Visual Studio 4.1.0.0

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli, scs

Getting this error comes up every time I try to pull (and push) items from Sitecore, using `Sitecore for Visual Studio`.

```
Matched module configurations: SC.Feature.Disclaimers
Sync operation with Sitecore failed
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.Internal.NullScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.(TypeLoadException)
       at SVS.VSIX.Logging.OutputWindowLogger.BeginScope[TState](TState state)
       at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<GetTreeNodesInternal>d__19.MoveNext()
```

I've been successful using the `Sitecore CLI` tools, but it doesn't appear to be working in Visual Studio at all.

- Visual Studio 2022 (64-bit) - v17.3.6
- Sitecore for Visual Studio - v4.1.0.0
- Sitecore CLI - v4.2.1-r00505
- Sitecore - v10.2

Comment: Can you check the compatibility? Try this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33146/sitecore-serialization-using-sitecore-cli-installation-error

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: @SumitBhatia Looks to be compatible, have added the CLI version I'm using to the post

Comment: @RichardSeal 10.2 in containers, also have tried with a local 10.2

Comment: @spyn do you know if this works in VS2022 v17.2.x?  Have seen some threads in slack discussing this as a possible issue with VS v17.3.x and Sitecore for Visual Studio

Comment: Any reason you're using the Visual Studio version? The cli does everything you need, and you don't have to load up VS 

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by upgrading Sitecore for Visual Studio to version 5.1.25.18